# Custom environment for second-level items not vertically aligning properly

Tags: macros, lists, vertical-alignment, environments

While writing a document with lots of `enumerate` environments, I wanted to add a little subset,

```
1. So the item is here 
     — and the inset is here
```

Which I did pretty easily. However, when I wanted to add to this to make it align paragraphs properly, I ran into problems. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with measuring the height of the `\lrbox`?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\newsavebox\mytextbox
\def\linelength{\linewidth-2em-1ex}
\newcommand{\two}[1]{%
    \vspace{3pt}\\\hspace*{1em}---\ 
    \begin{lrbox}{\mytextbox}\parbox[t]{\linelength}{#1}\end{lrbox}
    \parbox[t][\heightof{\usebox{\mytextbox}}][t]{\linelength}{\usebox{\mytextbox}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Long Items 
        \item \lipsum*[1]
            \two{Second Level Item}
            \two{\lipsum*[2]}
            \two{Another second level item}
        \item A first level item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

It doesn't seem to be measuring the box at all, and instead just assigning some kind of default height or something (`\parbox` doesn't have a default so it's confusing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really overcomplicating things: just use a nested `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Long Items
\item \lipsum*[1]
  \begin{itemize}[label=---,topsep=0pt]
  \item Second Level Item
  \item \lipsum*[2]
  \item Another second level item
  \end{itemize}
\item A first level item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is better, but still slower to type than my way—is there a way to redefine the itemize symbol and `topsep` globally?

Comment: @Ryan You can always say `\newenvironment{two}{\itemize[label=---,topsep=0pt]}{\enditemize}` and use `\begin{two}\item ... \item ... \end{two}`

Comment: Thanks, @egreg but no way to redefine the itimize symbol globally?

Comment: @Ryan Sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: is there a way to set itemize so that all  `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}` environments in the document use reduced spacing and em-dashes instead of bullets? Instead of specifying it each time the environment is used?

Comment: @Ryan `\setlist[itemize,1]{label=---,topsep=0pt}`

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly the best answer for typing the layout as fast as possible!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I *really* overcomplicated that...

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\def\linelength{\linewidth-2em-1ex}
\newcommand{\two}[1]{%
    \vspace{3pt}\\\hspace*{1em}---\ 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linelength}#1\\\end{minipage}
    \vspace*{-2\baselineskip}\\
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Long Items 
        \item \lipsum*[1]
            \two{Second Level Item}
            \two{\lipsum*[2]}
            \two{Another second level item}
        \item A first level item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

By simply using a `minipage`, there aren't any measurement issues at all.

**Output:**

> [image]